# how to convert unicode string on unicode format with python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, scrapy, string-conversion

I'm a student to learn python scrapy(crawler).

I want to convert unicode string to str in python.
but this unicode string is not common string.
this unicode is unicode format. please see below code.

```
# python 2.7
...
print(type(name[0]))
print(name[0])
print(type(keyword_name_temp))
print(keyword_name_temp)
...
```

I can see console like below, when run upper script.

```
$ <type 'unicode'>
$ 서용교 ## this words is korean characters
$ <type 'unicode'>
$ u'\\uc9c0\\ubc29\\uc790\\uce58\\ub2e8\\uccb4'
```

I want see "keyword_name_temp" as korean. but I don't know how to do...

I got the name list and keyword_name_temp from html code with http request.

name list fundamentally was String format.

keyword_name_temp fundamentally was unicode format.

please anybody help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u'\\uc9c0\\ubc29\\uc790\\uce58\\ub2e8\\uccb4'` contains real backslashes (backslash being an escape character in Python string literals, python interpreter prints backslash in strings as `\\`) followed by `u` and hex sequences, not literal Unicode characters U+C9C0 etc.
which are commonly written using [`\u` escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)
(Would that string happen to come from some JSON object perhaps?)

You can construct a JSON string out of it, and use `json.loads()` to transform to a unicode string:

Example in Python 2.7:

```
>>> s1 = u'서용교'
>>> type(s1)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> s1
u'\uc11c\uc6a9\uad50'
>>> print(s1)
서용교
>>> 
>>> 
>>> s2 = u'\\uc9c0\\ubc29\\uc790\\uce58\\ub2e8\\uccb4'
>>> type(s2)
<type 'unicode'>
>>>
>>> # put that unicode string between double-quotes
>>> # so that json module can interpret it
>>> ts2 = u'"%s"' % s2
>>> ts2
u'"\\uc9c0\\ubc29\\uc790\\uce58\\ub2e8\\uccb4"'
>>>
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(ts2)
u'\uc9c0\ubc29\uc790\uce58\ub2e8\uccb4'
>>> print(json.loads(ts2))
지방자치단체
>>>
```

Another option is to make it a string literal

```
>>> import ast
>>>
>>> # construct a string literal, with the 'u' prefix
>>> s2_literal = u'u"%s"' % s2
>>> s2_literal
u'u"\\uc9c0\\ubc29\\uc790\\uce58\\ub2e8\\uccb4"'
>>> print(ast.literal_eval(s2_literal))
지방자치단체
>>> 
>>> # also works with single-quotes string literals
>>> s2_literal2 = u"u'%s'" % s2
>>> s2_literal2
u"u'\\uc9c0\\ubc29\\uc790\\uce58\\ub2e8\\uccb4'"
>>> 
>>> print(ast.literal_eval(s2_literal2))
지방자치단체
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to switch to Python 3, where strings are Unicode by default.

Answer (score 0):

You string is unicode, and if you know the encoding: utf-8 for example, you can try

```
print name[0].decode("utf-8")
```